# My ajax call to spring rest services is pending forever

Tags: java, ajax, rest, call

My ajax call to spring rest services is pending state in my chrome browser and getting "provisional headers are shown not processing" in headers.

Once if i restart my tomcat server then the request is processing successfully.

The problem raising randomly...

please let me know the problem is from spring rest services side or ajax side??

appreciate your help.

Please find the screen shot from chrome browser.....

Once the request is in pending state...all the subsequent requests are also pending state...

Once the server has been started...then all the requests completes successfully...Please guide us how to solve this problem???

Please click below 1 to see the error pic..
!the request is in pending state....][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IekBE.png)

Comment: Did you check for any exception from server.

Comment: Sounds like server-side issues - check through your Tomcat logs for exceptions.

Comment: There is no error in logs, the problem happening not frequently...after restarting tomcat..the request processes successfully....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems there will be some problem from the services side. Even I had this issue long back in my application.

Please check the below things in your application

1. check in your database call...r u closing the db transaction properly.?
2. if you are using hibernate check the session has been closed or not?
3. check the memory allocation for tomcat???
4. check nay n/w problems like security issues?????

In my case we have not closed sessions properly in one of your services.